# How to replace a single character in one string with another string?

Tags: c

Looking to replace a character of a string with another string. I'd like it to work so that it can be used in the middle of a string and keeps the subsequent characters.

e.g. below would like to alter the string 'AND THE' to be 'ANDSPACETHE', currently outputting 'ANDSPACE' using strstr(). Ideally this could work multiple times in the same string e.g. 'AND THE CAT' --> 'ANDSPACETHESPACECAT'

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main ()
{
  char str[30] ="AND THE";
  char * pch;
  pch = strstr(str," ");
  if (pch != NULL){
    strncpy (pch,"SPACE",6);
  }
  printf("%s\n",str);
  return 0;
}
OUTPUT = ANDSPACE
DESIREDOUTPUT = ANDSPACETHE
```

Comment: `strncpy`merely copies a string. Before copying the string, you need to make room for by moving the rest of the string further, maybe by using the `memmove` function. A piece of paper and a pencil may be helpful here.

Comment: `man memcpy`, `man memmove`

Comment: It depends on what you are doing with the string. You might want to consider `fmemopen`

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char str[30] = "AND THE";
  char strtoinsert[] = "SPACE";

  char* pch = strstr(str, " ");
  if (pch != NULL) {
    // move remaining part of string further in order to make room
    memmove(pch + strlen(strtoinsert), pch + 1, strlen(pch));

    // copy the string to insert
    memcpy(pch, strtoinsert, strlen(strtoinsert));             
  }

  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

This will replace the first space encountered. With that base you should be able to figure out how to replace *all* spaces in a string.

Hint 1: repeat the whole thing until no more space is found.

Hint 2: if the string to insert contains spaces, then it's slightly more complicated as you cannot apply simply hint 1.

Hint 3: if you want to replace not just a single character but a whole word, this doesn't work either, you should be able to figure it out.